# How to specify delimiter for multi-value cookie in Django?

Tags: python, django

When creating a multi-value cookie in Django, how does one specify the delimiter between each key/value pair so that the cookie receives the delimiter's ASCII character representation instead of its octal representation?  Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
uid = 1
dev = 'computer'
cookie_value = 'uid:%s,dev:%s' % (uid, dev)
response.set_cookie(key="profile", value=cookie_value)
```

If I run this through the Python debugger, cookie_value contains:

```
'uid:1,dev:computer'
```

However, if I examine the cookie in my browser, I see this:

```
'uid:1\054dev:computer'
```

How do I make Django replace '\054' with a comma?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer lies [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/releases/1.1.2/#cookie-encoding)

> **Cookie encoding**
>
> To fix bugs with cookies in Internet Explorer, Safari, and possibly other browsers, our encoding of cookie values was changed so that the characters comma and semi-colon are treated as non-safe characters, and are therefore encoded as \054 and \073 respectively. This could produce backwards incompatibilities, especially if you are storing comma or semi-colon in cookies and have javascript code that parses and manipulates cookie values client-side.